# Is there a way to do a left join in office scripts?

Tags: javascript, office365, office-scripts

I have an excel workbook with two sheets / tables, "Source" and "Output". They have the same columns; important to this question are the columns "ID" (a unique identifier), "Error1", "Error2, and "Error3".

Currently I have a VBA macro that does the following: (1) If there is an "ID" in Output that is not in "Source" or the observations in any of the error columns are different between the two, remove that row from output (2) add all IDs from Source to Output that are not already present in Output. **Basically, this replaces the Output Table with a left join of Source and Output**

Unfortunately for me, I have to migrate this over to an office script. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried many things but haven't even come close to getting any output.

here is my original VBA code:

```
    Sub MasterMacro()
    Call RefreshAll
    Call RemoveRows
    Call AddRows
    Call ExpandTable
    Call SortTableValue
End Sub
Sub RemoveRows()
    Dim wsTable1 As Worksheet, wsTable2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowTable1 As Long, lastRowTable2 As Long
    Dim folderID As Range, rngCompare As Range
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the worksheet objects for Table 1 and Table 2
    Set wsTable1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Updated Error Check")
    Set wsTable2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Known Error Checks")

    ' Find the last row in each table
    lastRowTable1 = wsTable1.Cells(wsTable1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowTable2 = wsTable2.Cells(wsTable2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each Folder ID in Table 2
    For i = lastRowTable2 To 2 Step -1
        Set folderID = wsTable2.Cells(i, "B")
        Set rngCompare = wsTable1.Range("B2:B" & lastRowTable1).Find(folderID.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        ' Check if the Folder ID exists in Table 1
        If Not rngCompare Is Nothing Then
            ' Compare the values in columns C, D, and E
            If wsTable1.Cells(rngCompare.Row, "X").Value <> wsTable2.Cells(i, "X").Value _
                Or wsTable1.Cells(rngCompare.Row, "Y").Value <> wsTable2.Cells(i, "Y").Value _
                Or wsTable1.Cells(rngCompare.Row, "Z").Value <> wsTable2.Cells(i, "Z").Value _
                Or wsTable1.Cells(rngCompare.Row, "AA").Value <> wsTable2.Cells(i, "AA").Value _
                Or wsTable1.Cells(rngCompare.Row, "AB").Value <> wsTable2.Cells(i, "AB").Value _
                Or wsTable1.Cells(rngCompare.Row, "AC").Value <> wsTable2.Cells(i, "AC").Value Then
                ' Remove the row from Table 2
                wsTable2.Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Else
            ' Folder ID not found in Table 1, remove the row from Table 2
            wsTable2.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub AddRows()
    Dim table1Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table2Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table1Range As Range
    Dim table2Range As Range
    Dim table1Row As Range
    Dim table2Row As Range
    Dim folderID As Variant
    Dim folderIDColumn As Range
    Dim foundMatch As Boolean
    Dim lastRow As Long

    ' Set references to the Table1 and Table2 sheets
    Set table1Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Updated Error Check")
    Set table2Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Known Error Checks")

    ' Define the range for Table1 and Table2 data
    Set table1Range = table1Sheet.Range("B2", table1Sheet.Range("B" & table1Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row))
    Set table2Range = table2Sheet.Range("B2", table2Sheet.Range("B" & table2Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row))

    ' Find the last row in Table2
    lastRow = table2Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' Loop through each row in Table1
    For Each table1Row In table1Range
            folderID = table1Row.Value
            foundMatch = False
            ErrorIndicator = True
        If Not (table1Row.Offset(0, 28).Value = "*") Then
            ' Loop through each row in Table2
            For Each table2Row In table2Range
                ' Check if the folder ID matches in Table2
                If table2Row.Value = folderID Then
                    foundMatch = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next table2Row
    
            ' If no match is found, add the row to Table2
            If Not foundMatch Then
                ' Add the row from Table1 to Table2
                table1Row.EntireRow.Copy
                table2Sheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                lastRow = lastRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next table1Row

    ' Clear clipboard and display a message when the task is complete
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Sub ExpandTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Known Error Checks")
    
    'Set the table object
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("RobotCheckTable")
    
    'Find the Last Row
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Resize Table
    tbl.Resize tbl.Range.Resize(lastRow - tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row + 1)
End Sub


Sub SortTableValue()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim col As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Known Error Checks")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("RobotCheckTable")
    Set col = Range("RobotCheckTable[ItemID]")
    With tbl.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=col, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Sub RefreshAll()
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFhHQ.png)

Comment: Please attach your VBA code in the post.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to loop through each record and compare accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I correctly understand your question. Please try it.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let srcSht = workbook.getWorksheet('Source');
    let outSht = workbook.getWorksheet('Output');
    if (srcSht && outSht) {
        let srcTable = srcSht.getTables()[0];
        let outTable = outSht.getTables()[0];
        let cellsSrc = srcTable.getRange().getValues();
        let cellsOut = outTable.getRange().getValues();
        let aNewRange = [] = [];
        cellsSrc.forEach(valueSrc => {
            let lenRes = aNewRange.length;
            cellsOut.forEach(valueOut => {
                if (valueSrc.join() === valueOut.join()) {
                    aNewRange.push(valueSrc);
                    // console.log(valueSrc.join());
                    return;
                }
            })
            if (lenRes === aNewRange.length) {
                aNewRange.push(Array(valueSrc[0], "", "", ""));
            }
        })
        outTable.delete();
        outSht.getRange("A1").copyFrom(srcTable.getRange());
        outSht.getTables()[0].getRange().setValues(aNewRange);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

The code has been updated based on the logic outlined in the comments.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let srcSht = workbook.getWorksheet('Source');
    let outSht = workbook.getWorksheet('Output');
    if (srcSht && outSht) {
        let srcTable = srcSht.getTables()[0];
        let outTable = outSht.getTables()[0];
        let srcColCount = srcTable.getRange().getColumnCount()
        let srcValues = srcTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
        let outValues = outTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
        let aNewRange = [] = [];
        srcValues.forEach(valueSrc => {
            let lenRes = aNewRange.length;
            outValues.forEach(valueOut => {
                if (valueSrc[0] === valueOut[0]) {
                    if (valueSrc.slice(0, 4).join() === valueOut.slice(0, 4).join()) {
                        aNewRange.push(valueOut);
                    }
                    else {
                        aNewRange.push(valueSrc);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            })
            if (lenRes === aNewRange.length) {
                aNewRange.push(valueSrc);
            }
        })
        outTable.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
        outTable.getHeaderRowRange().getOffsetRange(1, 0)
            .getResizedRange(aNewRange.length - 1, 0)
            .setValues(aNewRange);
    }
    console.log('Done');
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! sorry if my original question was confusing this is getting at what I am trying to do. There are two changes from what you posted that I am trying to do. First, when the IDs are copied to the output table the errors should come along with them (the errors shouldn't be blank). Second, I tried to reduce the complexity of the table but in the full version of the table, there are other columns. What this means for the script is that for IDs 1 and 4 in this scenario, if there were other columns in the table the obs of that row should not be changed

Comment: @MichaelTaffe A screenshot of your data would help demonstrate the issue visually.

Comment: ive added my original VBA code and an image to the original post

Comment: @MichaelTaffe "IDs who's error indictor's have changed should be removed and re added". I think the third line (ID=2008) should be in this scenario. For "re-added", does Error 1~3 comes from "error list" or "commented error list"?

Comment: I may have explained it poorly but basically the source table (Error list) is a constantly refreshing table from powerquery. the output table (commented error list) is a sheet where users come to add comments to the errors. So I need the script to remove all rows from the output table whos ID has been removed from the source table as well as rows where the errors have changed. I then need all rows present on the source table missing from the output table to be added to the output table without overwriting anyone comments.

Comment: The code has been updated and can now reproduce the result shown in your screenshot.